# Change 3rd party css library using style integrated components

Tags: css

I am using 3rd party css component library. Now I have to make changes to their css.

For which I have to make changes to a specific class.

So How can I achieve that using style integrated components?

Comment: You create your own css file and applying your changes there, next you include your file in the HTML, **AFTER** the 3rd party css file (So you won't need to `!important` things)

Comment: @AlonEitan Can I not use style integrated components?

Comment: Not sure I know what it is... Sorry